# Have any one tried building Boost.Json static library?

Tags: boost, boost-build, boost-json

I am trying to build boost json to get libboost_json.a .
tried using --with-json option but it never generates .

my config says its building , but I do not see this lib getting generated ,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgUxz.png)

Comment: Never put in screenshots what you could just include in text thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as I no there may not be one.

Instead the [idea is](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/json/doc/html/json/quick_look.html) that you include `boost/json/src.hpp` in one of your own TUs. Of course, nothing stops you from putting that into your own static library, if that helps your build logistics.

Comment: Yes I didn't want to use header only version , due to a restriction that it must be defined in one and only one header file . My project has DTO objects and I want to put 'tag_invoke' for respective class file . When I use header only way , I throws exception while building .

btw I was able to build the .a for json as commented here : https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/issues/4040

Comment: @Rajeev please post your find so it helps others. And be specific, so they don't have to read the whole issue like I just did. By the way, you realize that putting a single TU as static library is (a) strictly equivalent (b) possibly _SAFER_ in the light of ODR rules? That's because when you integrate into your build script there's a much smaller chance of compiler version/flag differences

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Boost distribution and you build the libraries yourself, Boost.JSON should certainly get built. And binary distributions of Boost from specific packages should have a prebuilt Boost.JSON static and/or dynamic library.

Boost.JSON is available in Boost 1.75.0 and later.

Answer (score 0):

when u use b2 to build the boost library, just append this option like: 'cxxstd=11' or maybe u build in cpp std 14, then use this option to instead: 'cxxstd=14'

```
./b2 cxxstd=11 install
```